# Cakephp Meta Tags

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am trying to set up Meta Tags and Description for my website. The client wants to have for every page (CMS) different meta Tags.

Like the Set Title from the Action. Can i add the META tags for every action?

Comment: Sure, nobody is going to stop you from doing so...

Comment: how to add it? i mean is there any helper like the setTitle for meta. i am not able to find it in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `meta` function in the [HtmlHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::meta).

You can set the title, keywords, etc from each controller (and action) and the view will display them

Example:

`MyController.php` has

```
public function myaction() {
    $this->set('meta_keywords', 'my,keywords');
}
```

Put the below code in layout/view:

```
if (!empty($meta_keywords)) {
    echo $this->Html->meta(
        'keywords',
        $meta_keywords
    );
}
```